# Specify size of border box in Angular mat-cell

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm trying to stylize a mat-table and I'm wondering if what the UI designer specified is possible. What I'm trying to accomplish is something like this:

[Desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ydhrz.png)

In reality, I can't seem to get the border box to not take up the entire space of the mat-cell:

[Actual outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFHie.png)

I have the following html:

```
    <th class="th" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Passed</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let attempt" [ngClass]="{'box-green': attempt.passed, 'box-red': !attempt.passed}">
      {{ attempt.passed ? 'Passed' : 'Failed' }}
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```

With the following scss:

```
.box-red {
  max-width: 15px;
  max-height: 5px;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 2px solid red ;
  background-color: #f8d9dd;
  color: red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.box-green {
  max-width: 20px;
  max-height: 10px;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 2px solid green ;
  background-color: #d9f5d9;
  color: green;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

The values are different because I want to emphasize that the normal options that are suggested (modifying height, width, padding, max-width, max-height, etc etc) have not actually made a difference in the size of the box, it always fills the entire cell. Is there a way to modify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to add a `span` to your box element and then you can change its dimensions with `margin` and `padding`. See this example table code:

```
<table style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
    <tr>
        <th>Regulated</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Passed</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style={{ verticalAlign: 'middle' }}>
            Test
        </td>
        <td style={{ verticalAlign: 'middle' }}>
            11/01/2020 10:12 AM
        </td>
        <td style={{ verticalAlign: 'middle' }}>
            <span style={{
                border: '2px solid red',
                backgroundColor: '#f8d9dd',
                color: 'red',
                borderRadius: '10px',
                margin: '15px',
                padding: '5px'
            }}>
                Failed
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The import parts are setting `text-align: center` on the `table` itself, adding a class to the `td`s with `vertical-align: middle`, and then adding the `span`. Then once you have the `span` you can control its dimensions via `padding` and `margin`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I moved my [ngClass] into the inner <span> like
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let attempt" style="vertical-align: center">
      <span [ngClass]="{'box-green': attempt.passed, 'box-red': !attempt.passed}">
          {{ attempt.passed ? 'Passed' : 'Failed' }}
      </span>
    </td>
and it works.